# Could not modify reason phrase on HttpResponse object in asp vNext

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, http-response-codes

I have to set the reason phrase in my asp 5 middle-ware, not just the status code for the http response messages, but I could not found any way to do it.
The `StatusCode` property of the `Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpResponse` class is an `int` property for modifying the status code only, but not the reason text.

I understand, that the reason is set automatically according to the status code, but in my case I have to set it to custom values. Which is OK according to the [HTTP RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-6.1.1):

> [..] The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they MAY be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol. [..]

I'm currently using **beta-8** version of the asp 5 framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try:

```
Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = "some reason";
```

An `HttpStatusCodeResult` that also returns a reason could look like:

```
public class BadRequestResult : HttpStatusCodeResult
{
    private readonly string _reason;

    public BadRequestResult(string reason) : base(400)
    {
        _reason = reason;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }

        context.HttpContext.Response.HttpContext.Features.Get<IHttpResponseFeature>().ReasonPhrase = _reason;
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = StatusCode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Warning: `ReasonPhrase` is not supported in HTTP/2. That's why it is hidden in `IHttpResponseFeature`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult TestError() // id = error code 
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(301, "Your custom error text");
    }
}
```

Now check `http://localhost:33470/home/Testerror`

And look at Fiddler
[image]

Comment: Surprisingly it works through MVC 6. The problem is, that I need to do it from a standard asp middleware. I guess I'll dig into the internal code of MVC middleware itself to find out how it sets the reason phrase.

Comment: I've to correct myself. I updated the MVC framework to beta8, and now the mentioned constructor of HttpStatusCodeResult is gone. It has only one parameter, the status code as an int.